# Webscraping with bs4

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://bet.hkjc.com/football/index.aspx?lang=en"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

div = soup.find("div", {"class": "footballmaincontent"})
tables = div.find_all("table")
my_table = tables[2]

for row in my_table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')

    odds_list = []
    if len(cols) >= 10:
        match_no = (cols[0].text.strip())
        teams = (cols[2].text.strip())
        match_time = (cols[4].text.strip())
        home_odds = (cols[7].text.strip())
        away_odds = (cols[8].text.strip())
        draw_odds = (cols[9].text.strip())

        odds_row = (match_no,teams,match_time,home_odds,away_odds,draw_odds)
        odds_list.append(odds_row)

# Write to csv file
import csv
with open("odds_file.csv", "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in odds_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I tried to export the columns to a csv file by appending them to the "odds_list" inside the for loop. But turned out it has not written anything in the "odds_file".

I know theres something wrong with

```
odds_row = (match_no,teams,match_time,home_odds,away_odds,draw_odds)
```

But how can I append the list that I made into the csv file?

Comment: By using children[2] you are selecting the 3rd table in your DOM. Is that eactly what you want, the data fron 3rd table in DOM?

Answer (score -1):

You have `my_table` so use `find` and `find_all` with `my_table` to get `<tr>` and later `<td>` and then you can get `text` from `<td>`.

---

**EDIT:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://bet.hkjc.com/football/index.aspx?lang=en"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

div = soup.find("div", {"class": "footballmaincontent"})
tables = div.find_all("table")
my_table = tables[2]

for row in my_table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cols) >= 10:
        print(cols[0].text.strip(),'|',end='')
        print(cols[2].text.strip(),'|',end='')
        print(cols[4].text.strip(),'|',end='')
        print(cols[7].text.strip(),'|',end='')
        print(cols[8].text.strip(),'|',end='')
        print(cols[9].text.strip(),'|',end='')
        print()
        print('-'*40)
```

result

```
Match No. |Teams(Home vs Away) |Expected StopSelling Time |Home/Away/Draw | | |
----------------------------------------
FRI 9 |Romania U21 vs Luxembourg U21 |03/09 01:30 |Accept In Play Betting Only | | |
----------------------------------------
FRI 13 |St. Vincent and Grenadines vs USA |03/09 03:30 |35.00 |13.00 |1.02 |
----------------------------------------
FRI 14 |Honduras vs Canada |03/09 05:06 |1.45 |3.55 |6.50 |
----------------------------------------
FRI 15 |Trinidad and Tobago vs Guatemala |03/09 07:00 |1.67 |3.20 |4.70 |
----------------------------------------
```